# pass values from editor grid to java in extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have created an editor grid. 
[image]

After entering values in the grid, I want to pass this values to java and save it into database. I want to pass values after all rows are added into the grid.

I saw an example where the cell had a listener for change event, but I want to get all the rows of the grid.
 How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your store with a writer, e.g a JsonDataWriter. When all edits have been made on the grid, you would them call save() on the underlying store and then all record your new records will get sent in a batch to the server.

This kind of thing

```
var writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
    encode: true
});

// create the Data Store

    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root: 'data',
        idProperty: 'myid ',
        writer: writer,
        fields: ['myid', 'fieldA', 'fieldB', 'fieldB'],
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'YourUrl',
            method: 'POST'
        })
    });
```

Comment: should I add a listener to the grid and call the save() method from that?

Comment: No just calling save() on the store should be enough. Check out this example http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/writer/writer.html